# How to use text-overflow inside Bootstrap column?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, overflow

Suppose I have a row with fixed height and I inserted some text to its column. If it's too long I wanna it to be cut off and at the end of the line three dots supposed to be added like this:

[image]

I'm using **text-overflow: ellipsis;** attribute for this in my row but can't get it to work.

[image]

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Alexnotonfire/y6oatnzy/1/)

What am I doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text">    
    <div class="col-xs-4" style="border: solid">
 Some really long text!  Some really long text!  Some really long text!  Some really long text! The end! Some really long text! The end! Some really long text! The end! Some really long text! The end!
    </div>
  </div>        
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row {
    margin: 2px 0;
}

.text {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    height: 50px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do this using css, then try below code :

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">    
    <div class="col-xs-4" style="border: solid">
        <div class="text">
            Some really long text!  Some really long text!  Some really long text!  Some really long text! The end! Some really long text! The end! Some really long text! The end! Some really long text! The end!
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>        
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
    margin: 2px 0;
}

.text {
    display: block;
    display: -webkit-box;
    max-width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 1.2;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/41kuz29o/)

For understanding line clapming in css [Line Clamping](https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/)

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't seem to have dissappeared

Answer (score 4):

Define your CSS class and assign it to div where your are assigning col size like:-

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">    
    <div class="col-xs-4 trimText" style="border: solid">

            Some really long text!  Some really long text!  Some really long text!  Some really long text! The end! Some really long text! The end! Some really long text! The end! Some really long text! The end!

    </div>
  </div>        
</div>
```

where "trimText" CSS is:-

```
.trimText{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis
}
```

[Output Image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kRWC.png)

Answer (score -2):

Try it doing using js. It will show till 50 chars only.
Updated fiddle is - http://jsfiddle.net/y6oatnzy/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var showChar = 50;
    $('.more').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();

        if(content.length > showChar) {

            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

            var html = c +  '..';

            $(this).html(html);
        }  
    });   
});
```

Comment: JS Should be used only for functional work, CSS can handle this itself. Best rule of thumb: HTML = structure, CSS = style, JS = manipulation