# Bootstrap 4: column ordering in mobile

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to turn the following layout (desktop) [image]

into this responsive mobile:[image]

With the following HTML I can only display the first two ul's "in-block", but not the icon div or the newsletter div. I guess the problem starts with the LORAE IPSUM caps in the bottom of the second ul, but I don't know how to fix it. I've tried several solutions, but I just got more confused...Can someone help me acomplish this? I'm kind of new using bootstrap, thanks. The code:

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 col-md-2">
                 <h6>LORA IPSUM</h6>
                <ul >

                    <li>Lorae Ipsum</li>
                   <li>Lorae Ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorae Ipsum</li>


                </ul>

            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-md-2">
                <h6>LORAE IPSUM</h6>
                <ul >

                     <li>Lorae Ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorae Ipsum</li>
                    <li>Lorae Ipsum</li>
                    <li style="height:30px;"></li>            
                  </ul>


                <h6>LORAE IPSUM</h6>
                <h6>LORAE IPSUM</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-md-2 ">

                   <h6>LORAE IPSUM</h6>
                   <h6>LORAE IPSUM</h6>
                   <h6>LORAE IPSUM</h6>
                   <h6>LORAE IPSUM</h6>



            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-md-6 ">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6 col-md-6 ">
                        <h6>LORAE IPSUM</h6>
                        <a> 
                      <img class="img-fluid" 
 src="http://via.placeholder.com/40x40">
                        </a>
                        <a> 
                      <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/40x40">
                        </a>
                        <a> 
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/40x40">
                        </a>
                        <a> 
                          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/40x40">
                        </a>
                        <a> 
                         <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/40x40">
                        </a>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-6 col-md-6  ">
                        <h6>NEWSLETTER</h6>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <button>Subscribe</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="row" style="height:50px;">                            
                            </div>
                        <div class="row ">
                                <div class="col-12 part">
                                      <a>
                                    <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x30">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="row ">
                                <div class="col-12 part">
                                     <a>
                                    <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x30">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>


                </div>



            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're asking is "Is there a way to over flow text from cell-to-cell within the Bootstrap grid similar to InDesign?"

I have never come across such a thing. Bootstrap move cells in a grid, not really caring about content within it. [text-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33165066/how-to-use-text-overflow-inside-bootstrap-column) was the first thing I thought of, but that's probably the exact opposite of what you're looking for.

Comment: well, actually it's not what i'm looking for; I 've redesign the mobile so this can work. Thanks for the answer anyway :)